# Possible syntax error in VS 2012 mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have controller with method

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            return View(new AuthorizationModel { ReturnUrl = Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] }); 
        }
```

I have 2 projects 2012 and 2010.
On the view in VS 2010 works, in VS 2012 don't:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm<AccountController>(x => x.LogOn()))
```

Error text:Incorrect number of type parametres

Answer (score 0):

Are both projects the same version of MVC?

The only way I can get the same error is when I use the MVC3 futures project with an MVC4 app